# How to store video on S3 buccket without amplify in flutter?

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3

Whe tries to setup amplify with access and secret key I get this error.

```
AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:user/appName is not authorized to perform: amplify:CreateApp on resource: arn:aws:amplify:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxx:apps/*
at Object.extractError (C:\Users\josip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\protocol\json.js:52:27)
at Request.extractError (C:\Users\josip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\protocol\rest_json.js:55:8)
at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\josip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)        
at Request.emit (C:\Users\josip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
at Request.emit (C:\Users\josip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:688:14)
at Request.transition (C:\Users\josip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (C:\Users\josip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
at C:\Users\josip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\josip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\josip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:690:12)
at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\josip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:116:18)        
at Request.emit (C:\Users\josip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
at Request.emit (C:\Users\josip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:688:14)
at Request.transition (C:\Users\josip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (C:\Users\josip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
at C:\Users\josip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\josip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\josip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:690:12)
at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\josip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:116:18)        
at callNextListener (C:\Users\josip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:96:12)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\josip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js:313:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:228:7)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
```

message: 'User: arn:aws:iam::388135351221:user/reenact is not authorized to perform: amplify:CreateApp on resource: arn:aws:amplify:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:apps/*',
code: 'AccessDeniedException',
time: 2021-03-13T20:12:28.080Z,
requestId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
statusCode: 403,
retryable: false,
retryDelay: 73.65227073871408
}

Comment: Did you manage to upload a file to S3 without amplify?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this package - it has some very good examples (including S3):

https://pub.dev/packages/amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2

Looks like your problem is - you didn't setup your aws account properly, you can follow this guide to set it up correctly:

https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/installation/q/integration/js#option-2-follow-the-instructions

Comment: I found this package:  https://pub.dev/packages/aws_s3_upload , I will test it today. What you think about this package? Thank you...